# Sharing GPS signal to a Wifi-only iPad

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, gps, android

I want to share live GPS data from an Android smartphone to my iPad (4th generation wifi-only). I've read about BTstacks and other jailbreak tweaks, but **I don't want to jailbreak**! I have also read that there are some GPS receivers that are compatible with the iPad, so I think that maybe there is a method to connect the phone to the iPad that would allow the iPad to recognize the phone as a compatible GPS Bluetooth receiver.

Is there a good way to share GPS signal without jailbreaking the iPad?

Comment: I'd say just try using the android phone as a Wifi hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

"I'd say just try using the android phone as a Wi-fi hotspot" -  Matthieu Riegler

Unfortunately tethering makes no difference, the iPad uses known Wi-fi locations in its database to locate you. your tethering location won't be recorded or used.

Source: 2 days of trying different techniques and looking up workarounds. If tethered to a phone with GPS, but otherwise in a Wi-fi black spot, location will not be detected.

Apple has specifically disabled the GPS part of the Bluetooth stack for their non-GPS enabled machines, and then licence special GPS systems that can pass the information.

a standard bluetooth GPS is about $20, an apple enabled one begins at around $120, at which point it is cheaper to get a wifi enabled ipad.

Jailbreaking allows you to fix the disabled Bluetooth stack.

I'm still hoping to find a work around, but I haven't found one so far for their proprietary air print. people who have tried are removed from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround if you have a second (smart)phone. On that second phone use a service to share that phone’s location with yourself (eg, Find My). Your iPad, tethered to your phone, will get that shared location (with Find My via a notification, with other services it might be an email) and can display it on its mapping app.