# What location data will an Android phone provide to an iOS device that lacks GPS?

Tags: ipad, ipod, gps, android, geolocation

Will my iPad 4 Wi-Fi only (or an iPod touch) get live location data for navigation purposes if I connect to an Android mobile phone that is enabled as a Wi-Fi hotspot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing GPS signal to a Wifi-only iPad](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76473/sharing-gps-signal-to-a-wifi-only-ipad)

Comment: @bassplayer7 The questions are quite similar so I'll edit this to be more general about what data flows instead of a rephrasing of the original question.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Your flags are good - feel free to try editing things when you can hone in on something that would be of use - the OP can always revert things and no harm done if you walk away then. Ping us in the chat room if you want us to proof the first few edits / offer guidance.

Comment: @bmike, thanks for the pointers. Especially on this one, I wasn't able to discern where the OP wanted to take it. I'll certainly keep chat in mind as well.

Comment: @bassplayer7 great point - if you don't know of a clearer edit, then closing is the best course of action to get a question cleaned up and then reopened.

Answer (score 3):

When you tether an iOS device, it will have a live data connection and perhaps make some better use of any Wi-Fi signals that are in range for determining location, but in general - you won't get GPS like accuracy just because an iPad or iPod is connected to a phone (android or iOS) over Wi-Fi tethering.

Just like your computer can't really gain GPS data from a Wi-Fi router, the same holds for an andriod based Wi-Fi router that happens to be a phone.

There is no reason why this data couldn't be sent to an app and a GPS server could be conceived on Android or iOS to provide streaming data, but this isn't something that comes automatically or by-design from Wi-Fi tethering.